# Ionic v5 web media capture with capacitor - cordova_not_available

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native, capacitor

I am building an app with Ionic 5, Capacitor 2 and Angular 11.
I need to capture video and audio using [the media capture cordova plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media-capture).

I installed the following modules:

```
npm install cordova-plugin-media-capture
npm install @ionic-native/media-capture
```

And added MediaCapture to the providers of my app module.
Then I call *mediaCapture.captureVideo()* to retrieve a video ; unfortunately an exception is thrown when testing on a browser: `cordova_not_available`

[The github repo](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture) states this plugin is web-compatible, and its sources have a browser implementation. However the `window.navigator.device.capture` is missing to make this plugin work.

**Is it a bad configuration from my side? Or this cordova plugin wouldn't be compatible with capacitor?**

I made a repro : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v5-media-capture-capacitor?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Thank you for your help

Comment: I suppose you should build it via `ionic cordova build browser` to way to work in the browser. Should your logic work in the browser? I think, your logic should work fine on the real device.

Comment: Yes it should work in the browser too (the lib uses navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia for web). This command would integrate my app with cordova, however I would like to keep it with capacitor as it is the new official native runtime for Ionic. Most of Cordova plugins remains compatible with Capacitor.

Comment: I think you can't keep the same logic for the web and mobile with `MediaCapture` + `Capacitor`. I think you can try to set up `browser` build with `cordova` (and keep `capacitor` for mobile versions) or try pure js lib for recording video in web: https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a regular Angular version for the web, if anyone need it:

```
async browserCapture() {
  const stream: MediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(this.constraints);
  const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {mimeType: 'ogg'});
  const chunks: Blob[] = [];
  recorder.ondataavailable = (event: BlobEvent) => {
    if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
      chunks.push(event.data);
      this.zone.run(() => {
        this.recordChunks = [...chunks];
        this.cd.markForCheck();
      });
    }
  };
  this.recorder.onstop = () => {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      stream.getTracks().forEach(t => t.stop());
      if (chunks?.length) {
        this.upload(new Blob(chunks, {type: 'ogg'})); // use the blob result
      }
    });
  };
  recorder.start(500);
}
```